# Can't get value correctly from shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to save a value in the shared preferences in flutter then get it. But it's always returning `null`. The value is being retrieved from an API that is working fine in the backend.

Here is my code:

Method in which i'm getting the data from the api:

```
List<LastOrder>? lastOrders;
  var isLoaded3 = false;

  int od_id = 0;

    getLastOrderMethod() async {
        lastOrders = await RemoteService().getLastOrder(2);
        if (lastOrders != null) {
          setState(() {
            isLoaded = true;
          });
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 1,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                setState(() {
                  od_id = lastOrders![0].id;
                  print('getLastOrderMethod: $od_id');
                  saveIdOrder(od_id);
                });
                return;
              });
        }
      }
```

Method in which i'm trying to **save** the variable value in the shared preferences:

```
Future<bool> saveIdOrder(value) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print('save: $od_id');

    return await sharedPreferences.setInt('order_id', value);
  }
```

Method in which i'm trying to **get** the variable value in the shared preferences:

```
static Future getIdOrder() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final x = sharedPreferences.getInt('order_id');
    print('get: $x');

    return x;
  }


@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    print('intial ${od_id}'); => 0
    getIdOrder(); => null
    getLastOrderMethod();
    super.initState();
  }
```

I'd be glad for any kind of help!

Comment: 'Can somebody help me?' is not a "real question" by our community's standards! [Read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541) to learn why and how to ask a better question. You can also see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: First of all, 'Can somebody help me?' was never asked by me. Second, I clearly explained my problem which is that I'm always getting a null value although I have read it correctly from the database. With all my respect, I do not see the utility of your comment. Kind Regards!

Comment: can you include how you are fetching data from `getUserData`

Comment: I'm just fetching the order ID from getLastOrderMethod() and exactly inside the listView.builder(), the getUserData() is only created for reading the stored ID. I'll edit my post to add the initState()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by doing all the logic inside the listView.builder(), then updated the variable value inside a setState()

Answer (score 2):

`getIdOrder()` is a future method, it will take some time to fetch the data. While `initState` cant be `async` method, you can use `.then` and inside it call setState to update the ui. but Using FutureBuilder will be best option.

```dart
late final future = getIdOrder();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("${snapshot.data}"); // your widget
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
  );
}
```

More about using [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Thank you for that, the thing is that I do not want to show it in my ui. I just need to get the ID and save it to the shared preferences so I can use it later on while calling another method. To make it even more clear, the user will create an order, and then will add items to that order. At last I only need to get the ID and save it to the shared preferences.

Comment: then you can try with initState `.then` it will be `getIdOrder().then((value){... do your stuffs})`

Comment: I don't know if you got it or not, but the value of the ID gets updated in getLastOrderMethod(), shouldn't I only call it on initState()?